# Resize 5 Tb ext4 empty drive with Gparted takes 40 hs

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, gparted, ext4

I have an external 5 Tb drive connected via a USB3 port.

I just formatted it to ext4, so it's completely empty.

I told Gparted to resize it so as to leave some ~100 Gb of unallocated space  at the end, and it's telling me it will take +40hs to finish (!)

Is this expected? Why would it take so long to resize an empty drive?

[image]

Comment: it looks like you have moved the partition to the right (so it says on your screenshot) (might be an unnoticed mouse movement while you were doing the resize). A shrink of an empty drive should be almost instant.If you read what gparted has done and is about to do - I do not see what else would cause this.

Comment: I moved the partition *to the left*, leaving unallocated space *to the right*. I also though that shrinking an empty partition should be instantaneous. Should I cancel the process?

Comment: Now I see it, not sure what that *"move file system to the right"* means...

Comment: I would and then do the shrink without moving. Moving the partition will very probably start a copy process again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shrinking an empty ext4 filesystem is indeed very fast, but you're also moving the beginning of the partition.

Now, instead of relocating the end and chopping it off, every single bit in the large partition must be shifted in the direction you moved the partition.  The partition is very large, so it'll take a long time.

You should probably recreate the filesystem because it's empty to begin with.  Recreating the filesystem will be very fast.